# How to install VIM on Linux when I don't have root permissions?

Tags: linux, installation, vim

I've got some troubles when I try to install Vim on Linux while I don't have a root account. The error information is shown below:

[image: errorinfo]

How can I solve this? Can I install it in another directory other than `/usr/local/bin/vim`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`make install DESTDIR=~/.local`, then make a symlink in `~/bin` to `~/.local/bin/vim`.

Comment: Do I need to create a fold named `.local` or it's just a normal name?

Comment: It is safest to create the destination directory yourself.

Comment: I got a vim diretory like `/home/apache/.local/usr/local/share/vim/vim72` after finish the two steps.Anything wrong?

Comment: You'll need to pass a different `--prefix` option to `configure` as well then.

Comment: it would be greatly appreciated if you can write all steps down in the answer.

Comment: ./configure --prefix=~/.local && make install

Comment: this answer doesn't really work well with the standard convention of `.local/bin` and `.local/share`; instead making vim create its own hierarchy beyond that: `.local/usr/loca/bin` and so on. I would follow the answer by @luc-hermitte

Answer (score 24):

I often install things with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local && make && make install` where I'm not root. That's the way to proceed.

This works with most software. Vim is in no way different here.

Note that in vim case, I actually configure with the following options (as well) `--disable-perlinterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-multibyte --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge` as I like my version of Vim to be quite complete.

Comment: After this step, I add my ~/local/bin to the PATH:
export PATH="/home/youruser/.local/bin:$PATH"

Comment: `./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local --enable-multibyte --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge --enable-python3interp --enable-fail-if-missing`

I omitted the parts about PERL and Ruby (as I don't have Ruby on the target machine)

Comment: For those wondering where `configure` comes from: I believe this answer assumes you've downloaded vim source from https://github.com/vim/vim.

Comment: Yes indeed. At the time I was getting vim sources from elsewhere, but now github is indeed where I get sources to built it (with the options I like) and to install it wherever I want/can.

Answer (score 8):

1. Create local user path:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/usr/local
   ```
2. Downloaded latest version of `ncurses` from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/
3. Install `ncurses`:

   ```
   cd <path_to_ncurses_downloaded_folder>
   tar -xzvf <ncurses>.tar.gz
   cd <ncurses_extracted_folder>
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/local
   make
   make install
   ```
4. Clone `vim-repo` with

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git
   ```
5. Install vim with:

   ```
   cd vim/src
   LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/usr/local/lib ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/local
   make
   make install
   ```
6. Set PATH with

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/bin
   ```

Answer (score 0):

step 1: make install DESTDIR=~/.local (make your local dir if it is not present)

step 2:  export PATH=$PATH:/remote/users/yourusername/.local/bin