# Missing functions when installing vim to a local directory

Tags: vim, compile

I tried to install vim on a local directory by giving the `--prefix` command when running `./configure`. More specifically, this was what I did:

```
# Installed ncurses locally on $HOME/local/gpu2
cd vim/src
LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/local/gpu2 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/gpu2
make
make install
```

based on the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1423505/1154376).

I seem to have successfully installed it in `$HOME/local/gpu2/`. However, I ran `vim` and noticed that a number of things didn't run properly. For example, typing

- `:Ex` gives me the error: `E492: Not an editor command: Ex`
- `:syntax on` gives me the error: `E484: Can't open file "/home/tshmak/local/gpu2"/share/vim/syntax/synta x.vim`. Note the quotes inserted into the directory name.
- `:help` gives me `E433: No tags file` and `E149: Sorry, no help for help.txt`

Can someone shed some light on what may be wrong, and or how I should have compiled vim?

---

### EDIT:

As requested by @iskyfire, the following is the output from `vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Aug  5 2020 15:53:06)
Included patches: 1-2214
Compiled by tshmak@gpu-server2
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       +X11
+diff              +modify_fname      -sound             +xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: ""/home/tshmak/local/gpu2"/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L/home/tshmak/local/gpu2/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lnsl  -lacl -lattr -ldl
```

Comment: Hello, in order to best determine the errors that you are being given by vim, can you provide the output of `vim --version` from your terminal?

Comment: I see the quotes inside the fallback and those definitely shouldn't be there. I'm still looking for potential modifications. 

However, the `:help` command error is a separate issue that happens when you compile vim. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145819/vim74-e149-sorry-no-help-for-help-txt/42165987#42165987